# Make list generic for JsonConvert.DeserializeOjbect<List<MyObject>>(json)

Tags: c#, json, list, generics

I want to deserialize a jsonString that contains an array of objects, e.g.:

```json
[
    {"prop1": 1},
    {"prop2": 2}
]
```

This code works just fine:

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObjectType>>(jsonString);
```

So I am able to get the object type for the list, I fail implementing it.

... but how do I make the list generic?

Comment: My answer may not be helpful, but in case you want to handle the objects with possible different types, maybe you can consider for `JArray` type (`JArray.Parse(jsonString)`). It is much easier to extract value than implement a converter for generic type.

Comment: List<T> is already generic.

Comment: If you want to accept arbitrary key-value lists you need to use a collection that can represent that list, i.e. something like a `Dictionary<string, int>` or `Dictionary<string, object>`. Or you could take the generic type argument from the calling code, assuming that there is *something* that knows the actual expected type of the json.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I ended up parsing to jArray as @YongShun proposed. Then going through the items in the array and calling DeserializeObject(item, type); Works for me ...